# can anyone upload a file using script through input text box

Tags: php, html

attackers try to down my websites. They always try to rename index.php file. sometimes they did that. How it possible.Is there is any way to upload file from input text box using script..?

Comment: there are tons of way to inject any code into any server .  which is called site's vulnerability.  So you sure that's the way attacker choose

Comment: This question is impossible for us to answer. There are too many ways a server can be breached and we know _nothing_ about your setup. We would need to have access to the server and do some extensive tests, which is _way_ too broad for SO.

Comment: how can i prevent code injection

Comment: Again, that question is _way_ too broad. There are many ways an attacker can breach your server. It would literally be impossible to go through them all here.

Comment: okey.....................

Comment: @Dwith read through ALL of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

dont use $_POST["ur_variable"] directly and insert it in database
Instead use sanitize function like mysqli_real_escape_string().
u can also checkout this link for prevention from xss attacks.
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_validation.asp